# IllegalArgumentException Key must be integer error in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Am getting the subject error when trying to do a simple thread macro.

Keyword defines

```
(def entityType (keyword "name"))
(def entityURI (keyword "uri"))
```

I have the following 'lazy' sequence:

```
(def m1
    (({:uri "...#OWLClass_82601afd_b43d_43b4_94fe_2836f40009ca", :name "foo"} 
    {:uri "...#OWLClass_8c6759f0_a165_4a09_a9d8_2603bb106fc6", :name "bar"}))
```

Here is the REPL thread:

```
(->> (first m1)
     (map (fn [rec] (rec entityType))))
```

And the resulting error:

```
IllegalArgumentException Key must be integer  clojure.lang.APersistentVector.invoke (APersistentVector.java:265)
```

Anyone with any insight?

Comment: Actually you are supposed to get NullPointerException once you meet the definition of m1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code I am *guessing* you want `m1` to be declared like this:

```
(def m1
  (list (list {:uri "...#OWLClass_82601afd_b43d_43b4_94fe_2836f40009ca", :name "foo"} 
              {:uri "...#OWLClass_8c6759f0_a165_4a09_a9d8_2603bb106fc6", :name "bar"})))
```

Thus:

```
(->> (first m1)
     (map (fn [rec] (rec entityType))))
;=> ("foo" "bar")
```

Is this what you were after?

**EDIT**:

Based on your comment I've understood that the structure of `m1` is flatter, like this:

```
(def m1
  (list {:uri "...#OWLClass_82601afd_b43d_43b4_94fe_2836f40009ca", :name "foo"} 
        {:uri "...#OWLClass_8c6759f0_a165_4a09_a9d8_2603bb106fc6", :name "bar"}))
```

Based on this you can just do `(map (fn [rec] (rec entityType)) m1)` and drop the `->>`.

Comment: m1 (which is actually generated from another call) is (type m1) clojure.lang.LazySeq and (type (first m1)) is clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap. If I write (->> (first m1)
     (map (fn [rec] (type rec))))… Frank: there are other 'keys' that I didn't show in the question/post.
I get:
(clojure.lang.MapEntry clojure.lang.MapEntry clojure.lang.MapEntry clojure.lang.MapEntry clojure.lang.MapEntry clojure.lang.MapEntry clojure.lang.MapEntry)

Comment: In that case instead of a `->>` you can just use `(map (fn [rec] (rec entityType)) m1)`.

Comment: but I'm building up the thread to process the entire list (m1) so I need the macro.

Comment: Then just do `(->> m1 (map (fn [rec] (rec entityType))))`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who wind up on this post after searching this error string, be careful you are not accidentlly trying to assoc a (keyword ...) to a vector:'

> (def foo [])
>
> (assoc-in foo [:aaa (keyword "b-bb")] ["obj"] )